# Insert using a select in typeorm

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I want to reproduce a query where the values are the result of a select in typeorm.
The query i want to reproduce is the one i provide here, but i can't find anything in typeorm documentation.
(Isnt important what the query does for the answer, i only need to know how to write that "`SELECT`" in typeorm)

http://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_query_builder_insertquerybuilder_.insertquerybuilder.html#values

```
INSERT INTO `furgpezzo`(`giacenza`, `giacenzaMin`, `pezzoBarcode`, `furgoneTarga`, `invStandardId`) 
    select '0', '5', '234234234234', f.`furgoneTarga`, '1'
    from `furgpezzo` f
    where f.`invStandardId` = '1'
    group by f.`furgoneTarga`
```

something like:

(Edit:)

```
return await this.dmDatabase.getRepository(FurgPezzo)
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(FurgPezzo)
    .values(   //here put my select   )
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes you can. From [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-subqueries):

> You can easily create subqueries. Subqueries are supported in `FROM`,
>   `WHERE` and `JOIN` expressions.

Refer to the following posts for example: [TypeORM subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553523/typeorm-subqueries), [Typeorm subquery add select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136111/typeorm-subquery-add-select).

You can use subqueries:

```
return await this.dmDatabase.getRepository(InvStandard)
    .insert()
    .values(qb => {qb.select(FurgPezzo).where()})//here put my select 

// with subquery->

return await this.dmDatabase.getRepository(InvStandard)
    .insert()
    .values(qb => {qb.select(FurgPezzo).where(
            const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
                // your subquery builder
            return "your condition " + subQuery;)})
```

Comment: I wrote a bad answer... I have to edit it. What i want was use that subquery on "values". i can't find a way

Comment: @MarcoZanonfurbino1 Not sure if it's possible to use on values using the current template. But possible alternative I can think of is using the raw query and run it; example: `await manager.query('INSERT statement...
    select statement...')`

Comment: I did so and the problem is solved for now.
Thank you very much

Comment: This answer is out of context

Comment: `.values()` doesn't even take queryBuilder as parameters.

Comment: not sure why this is the accepted answer, it doesn't work as mentioned by @Vicary. Was this valid at the time?

Comment: @Shinjo please remove your answer, TypeORM doesn't allow subqueries for values. Just check the doc and test the code.

Answer (score 10):

This is the neatest solution I could come up with, hope it helps future explorers. The answer comments inspired me.

```
const [selectQuery, params] = this.entityManager
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select("user.name")
  .from(User, "user")
  .where("user.id IN (:...ids)", {
    ids: [
      "87654321-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc",
      "a9876521-aabb-ccdd-ffaa-123abcdefccc",
    ],
  })
  .getQueryAndParameters();

await this.entityManager.query(
  `
INSERT INTO dummy("name")
${selectQuery}
`,
  params
);
```

Comment: This does not work because generated query does not preserve column order of your select statement.