# Insert into select using typeom

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I try to execute an "INSERT INTO SELECT" using typeorm in a nestjs project.
I've correctly sett the subscriber part, but when I want to execute my function, I have an error

> (node:4592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: statement.replace is not a function
> (node:4592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Here my function

```
async insertIntoSelect(id) {
    const qb = this.MyOperationRepository.createQueryBuilder();
    return await qb
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(EntityA, ['FieldA', 'FieldB'])
      .select(id, 'FieldB')
      .from(EntityB, 'EntityB')
      .where('EntityB.id= ' + id)
      .printSql()
      .execute();
  }
```

I don't know if it's my function or the process which is not corrrect.
If someone have an exemple or see something wrong in my code, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is [not currently supported in TypeOrm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4374). You either need use a raw query, use a subquery, or perform multiple queries.

More possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363201/insert-using-a-select-in-typeorm).